# How can I verify my true genetic relationship with my close relatives with simple physical traits?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, human-anatomy, human-genetics

**Question**
I don't know if it is ethical to ask a question like that, but I would like to know every simple physical trait that I can observe on me, my parents and my siblings which are regulated by a single or really low number of genes.  I don't want any disease-related traits, just simple traits that could illustrate genetic relatedness.

**Already done search**
During my research I've found about:

- Hair on the second phalanx which is controlled by a single gene and absence of hair being recessive. (Recessive means you need two copies of the allele to have the trait absence of hair!) So if both parents have the trait absence of hair (on second phalanx), every child must have it as well.
- Merged ear lob is also a recessive trait.

These are some for which I am not sure of the underlying genetics.

- Hair in V on the forehead
- Presence of dimples
- Able to make a U with tongue
- Able to detect Phenylthiocarbamide (PTC)

**Don't hesitate to answer with references**

**EDIT**: This [site](http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/mythdigithair.html) is saying that both hair in second phalanx and merged ear lobs are not as simple as they seemed...

Question: What trait can I use to illustrate genetics?

Comment: What do you mean by "physical trait"? I assumed you meant something visible, but "Able to detect Phenylthiocarbamide" doesn't come under that. Put another way, what would a "non-physical" trait be?

Comment: Well, it would mean something easy to assess for a classroom (and no lab studies), To be honest I wasn't thinking about PTC when first writing the question. for example blood type is not easy to assess without a lab. I agree physical is not the best way to say that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the answers for your four questions:

- Widow's peak (hair in V): **dominant**: [Dominant and recessive characteristics, blinn.edu](http://www.blinn.edu/socialscience/ldthomas/feldman/handouts/0203hand.htm); [Dominant Inheritance, Genetics Generation](http://knowgenetics.org/dominant-inheritance/)
- Dimples: **irregular; tendancy toward dominant ***: [Mendelian Genetics, uni.edu](https://sites.uni.edu/walsh/genetics.html); [What Is the Genotype for Dimples?, seattlepi.com](http://education.seattlepi.com/genotype-dimples-4182.html); [Understanding Genetics, genetics.thetech.org](http://genetics.thetech.org/ask/ask188)
- Curling tongue: **complex; tendancy toward dominance**: [Myths of Human Genetics, udel.edu](https://udel.edu/~mcdonald/mythtongueroll.html); [Debunking the biggest genetic myth of the human tongue, Cathrine Woods](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/science/genetic-myth-textbooks-get-wrong)
- Phenylthiocarbamide detection: **dominant**: [Phenylthiocarbamide tasting, Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/phenylthiocarbamide-tasting); [Genetic study of phenylthiocarbamide (PTC) taste perception, Egyptian Journal of Medical Human Genetics, Volume 13, Issue 2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1110863012000043); [PTC The Genetics of Bitter Taste, genetics.utah.edu](http://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/basics/ptc/)

Hope it helps!

<sub>*See comments</sub>

Comment: So i shouldn't use Curling tongue to illustrate genetic trait :-(.

Comment: @Untitpoi probably not.  There's even some discussion about the phenylthiocarbamide gene being more complex than a simple dominance.

Comment: I found that Dimples is irregular as it can change along the life (like curling tongue) http://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/basics/observable/

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I wasn't aware of that one.  I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: Well these was more complicated than i have expected, almost no trait are really controlled by one gene... the only one i have found with no doubt on it is dry earwax http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/mythearwax.html

Comment: "no trait" is a bit of a harsh judgement when so many single genes control so obvious traits like having a symmetrical body plan, two fore and two hindlimbs, five fingers... :) to find inter-individual differences within one species, you're looking at extremely high-level genetics.

Comment: The other side of this is that you're unlikely to find common genetic traits that are shared by close relatives, yet not fairly common in the generatl population.